# How to record system internal audio with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make code to record audio and video with python, i found a way to record video but i didn't find way to record audio, could any one help to record video and audio(system internal audio) with python?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into PyAudio: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/

```
pip install PyAudio
```

the documentation is here

https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/

also, I did a quick google search and found some code snippets online that use pyaudio they might be worth the look.

Comment: here is a link to one of those code snippets I was talking about. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/how+to+record+system+sound+python

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyAudio and take a look to the record example in the [documentation](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

This example get the default input device in your machine, like your mic. On linux you can emulate an input device with the output with loopback module in pulseaudio. On windows you can use StereoRemix to do this.